# Nested Right Isosceles Triangles Java

Tags: java, recursion

I'm having quite a bit of trouble getting my code to work. In my code, nested right isosceles triangles are suppose to be drawn like this: [image]
I'm not sure if my code will work either since once I run it, the triangles are not drawn. I am given this error

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError

and I am not sure how to fix it. Help?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Ornament extends JPanel
{
 public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
 {
    super.paintComponent( g ); // Call JPanel's paintComponent method
                               // to paint the background
    drawTriangles( g, 100, 80, 64 );
 }


/**
 * Draws an ornament made of triangles in Graphics g with the base midpoint
 * at (x, y) and base half-length r
 */
 public void drawTriangles( Graphics g, int x, int y, int r )
 {
    g.drawLine( x + r, y, x - r, y ); 
    g.drawLine( x + r, y, x, y - r );
    g.drawLine( x - r, y, x, y - r );

    if ( r == 4 )
    {
        drawTriangles( g, x-r , y, r );
        drawTriangles( g, x-r , y, r );
    }

    else {

        drawTriangles( g, 36+r , y, r );
        r --;
    }

 }


public static void main( String[] args )
 {
    JFrame w = new JFrame( "Triangles" );
    w.setBounds( 300, 300, 200, 120 );
    w.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    Ornament panel = new Ornament();
    panel.setBackground( Color.WHITE );
    Container c = w.getContentPane();
    c.add( panel );
    w.setResizable( false );
    w.setVisible( true );
 }
}
```

Comment: Your `drawTriangles` doesn't have a base case.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `drawTriangles` with `r` not equal to 4, it is going to keep calling itself again and again with the same `r`. The `r--` is never reached.

Try putting the `r--` before the recursive call in the else clause.

Comment: That won't help the case where `r=4`, which is also broken.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to proceed once you reach `4` (your base case) so you could write the `if` statement as

```
if (r != 4) {
    drawTriangles(g, 36 + r , y, r - 1);
}
```

This won't produce the graphical output as shown in the original description but will prevent the `SOE`

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an infinite loop.
this is what is happening in the first series of iterations:

```
drawTriangles( g, 100, 80, 64 );
  // draw lines
  drawTriangles( g, 136 , 80, 64 );
    // draw lines
    drawTriangles( g, 172 , 80, 64 );
      // draw lines
      drawTriangles(g, 208, 80, 64);
      r--;
    r --;
  r--;
```

and so forth.
however the r-- is never reached because you go into the next level of recursion first.
if you swap drawTriangles and r-- , at least r would be getting smaller, though not very fast. I would have expected r/2 or something there.